# How to prevent a row add to GridView during binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

We have a `GridView` that bind to some data and it look like this:

```
RowNumber        Id                   Desc
-------------------------------------------
   1                20                  Desc1   
   2                30                  Desc2   
   3                40                  Desc3   
   4                50                  Desc4
```

I create `RowNumber` using this code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSlNo" runat="server" Text='<% #Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So considering that during data binding, I don't want show second row but I want keep RowNumber for it. The data should show like this:

```
RowNumber        Id                   Desc
-------------------------------------------
   1                20                  Desc1   
   3                40                  Desc3   
   4                50                  Desc4
```

How I can prevent a row add to GridView during Databinding?

Comment: The most straightforward way simply is  not to select it from your dbms.

Comment: Yes but How I want to keep RowNumber.If I don't select it my `RowNumber`s are incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow){
        e.Row.Visible = SomeCondition;
    }
}
```

Where someCondition is your checking.

Comment: Nice! Anyway, there is a bad practice to fetch unused rows from data source because it is wasting of performance.

Comment: The Tim Schmelter's solution is much better for the case when your condition could be checked on SQL layer.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is: don't select this row from DBMS.

For example(in SQL-Server >=2005):

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT Id                   
           ,Desc
           ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Order By ID)As RowNumber
    FROM Table
)
SELECT * FROM cte
where RowNumber != 2
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: question has a condition - keep the ID for that hidden row.

Comment: @Trailmax: The OP doesn't want to keep the ID but he wants to ensure that the RowNumber is calculated correctly even if there's a missing row. That is what  [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) does in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[OnRowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) is your friend here

in ASPX file, for datagrid specify OnRowDataBound event

```
<GridView ID="ResultsGridView" runat="server"   onRowDataBound="ResultsGridView_RowDataBound">
```

then go in CS file:

```
protected void ResultsGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells[1].value)//check your value here
    {
        e.Row.Visible = false;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it on the Database side

```
select * from 
(
select Row_Number() over(order by ID) RowNumber,        Id,   Desc
) a
where RowNumber<>2
```

Comment: I would not go there. Sometimes DB side scripts are not available to change. Or you need to show the same dataset depending on user actions. Also it is a condition in the question that ID is still required.

Answer (score 0):

try like this, you can call server side function using Eval, if it returns true, then use RowNumbe, or else assign empty value to it

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSlNo" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Eval("yourColumn") ==SomeCondition ? (Eval(Container.DataItemIndex + 1) : Eval("")) %>'></asp:Label>
```